Problema al mapear productos del carrito en React Context
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de comercio electrónico utilizando React y Context API. En mi componente Checkout, intento mapear los productos del carrito para mostrarlos. Sin embargo, me encuentro con un problema: los productos obtenidos a través de getProductById  al refrescar la pagina me devuelven undefined, aunque el carrito se muestra correctamente. Hice la prueba con un console.log del carrrito y productos al refrescar, antes de hacerlo lo muestra correctamente y despues no, me devuelve undefined el getProductById
    import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react"
    import {
      useUserLocalStorage,
      useCarritoLocalStorage,
    } from "../customHooks/useLocalStorage"
    export const ProductsContext = createContext()
    
    export const ProductsProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const [userData, setUserData] = useUserLocalStorage()
      const [carritoData, setCarritoData, clearCarritoData] =
        useCarritoLocalStorage()
    
      const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState(userData)
      const [carrito, setCarrito] = useState(carritoData)
      useEffect(() => {
        setUserData(usuario)
      }, [usuario])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setCarritoData(carrito)
      }, [carrito])
    
      const [productos, setProductos] = useState([])
    
      //remplazar con peticion de la api
      useEffect(() => {
        setProductos([
          {
            id: 1,
            nombre: "Producto 1",
            precio: 15,
            imagen: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
            descripcion: "asdaaddasdddddddddddddddass",
            stock: 13,
            cantidad: 0,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            nombre: "Producto 2",
            precio: 15,
            imagen: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
            descripcion: "asdaaddasdddddddddddddddass",
            stock: 3,
            cantidad: 0,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            nombre: "Producto 3",
            precio: 20,
            imagen: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
            descripcion: "asdaaddasdddddddddddddddass",
            stock: 10,
            cantidad: 0,
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            nombre: "Producto 4",
            precio: 150,
            imagen: "https://picsum.photos/200/200",
            descripcion: "asdaaddasdddddddddddddddass",
            stock: 2,
            cantidad: 0,
          },
        ])
      }, [])
    
      const [vbCarrito, setVbCarrito] = useState(false)
      const [preferenceId, setPreferenceId] = useState("")
      const [page, setPage] = useState("inicio")
      const [pedidoAprobado, setPedidoAprobado] = useState(false)
    
      function incrementarCantidad(id) {
        setCarrito((prevCarrito) =>
          prevCarrito.map((item) => {
            const product = getProductById(item.id)
            if (product.id === id && item.cantidad < product.stock) {
              return { ...item, cantidad: item.cantidad + 1 }
            }
            return item
          })
        )
      }
    
      function decrementarCantidad(id) {
        setCarrito((prevCarrito) =>
          prevCarrito.map((item) => {
            const product = getProductById(item.id)
            if (product.id === id && item.cantidad > 1) {
              return { ...item, cantidad: item.cantidad - 1 }
            }
    
            return item
          })
        )
      }
      function vaciarCarrito() {
        setCarrito([])
      }
    
      function eliminarProducto(id) {
        setCarrito((prevCarrito) => prevCarrito.filter((item) => item.id !== id))
        clearCarritoData()
      }
    
      const getProductById = (productId) => {
        return productos.find((product) => product.id === productId)
      }
    
      return (
        <ProductsContext.Provider
          value={{
            productos,
            setProductos,
            carrito,
            setCarrito,
            vbCarrito,
            setVbCarrito,
            incrementarCantidad,
            decrementarCantidad,
            vaciarCarrito,
            eliminarProducto,
            preferenceId,
            setPreferenceId,
            page,
            setPage,
            pedidoAprobado,
            setPedidoAprobado,
            usuario,
            setUsuario,
            getProductById,
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
      )
    }

checkout.js
    import React, { useContext, useState } from "react"
    import { ProductsContext } from "../../../context/ProductsContext"
    import modales from "../modales.module.scss"
    import { PagoButton } from "../pago/PagoButton"
    
    const CheckoutPage = () => {
      const { carrito, getProductById } = useContext(ProductsContext)
      const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        nombre: "",
        telefono: "",
        email: "",
        calle: "",
        ciudad: "",
        infoAdicional: "",
        carrito: carrito,
      })
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value })
      }
    
      const calcularSubTotal = (precio, cantidad) => precio * cantidad
    
      const calcularTotal = () =>
        carrito.reduce((total, prod) => {
          const product = getProductById(prod.id)
          return total + calcularSubTotal(product.precio, prod.cantidad)
        }, 0)
    
      return (
        <section className={modales.CheckoutPageContainer}>
          <form className={modales.CheckoutForm}>
            <div className={modales.PersonalSection}>
              <h2>Datos Personales</h2>
              <input
                type='text'
                name='nombre'
                placeholder='Nombre Completo'
                value={formData.nombre}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <input
                type='tel'
                name='telefono'
                placeholder='Teléfono'
                value={formData.telefono}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <input
                type='email'
                name='email'
                placeholder='Email'
                value={formData.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <textarea
                name='infoAdicional'
                placeholder='Información Adicional'
                value={formData.infoAdicional}
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className={modales.AddressSection}>
              <h2>Dirección de Envío</h2>
              <input type='text' placeholder='Pais' value='Argentina' readOnly />
    
              <input
                type='text'
                name='direccion'
                placeholder='Numero de la casa y nombre de la calle'
                value={formData.direccion}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <input
                type='text'
                name='ciudad'
                placeholder='Ciudad'
                value={formData.ciudad}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <input
                type='text'
                name='provincia'
                placeholder='Provincia'
                value={formData.provincia}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
              <input
                type='text'
                name='codigoPostal'
                placeholder='Codigo Postal'
                value={formData.codigoPostal}
                onChange={handleChange}
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div className={modales.OrderSummary}>
              <h2>Resumen del Pedido</h2>
              <div className={modales.OrderItems}>
                {carrito &&
                  carrito.map((prod, index) => {
                    const product = getProductById(prod.id)
                    console.log(product)
                    console.log(carrito)
                    return (
                      <div key={index} className={modales.OrderItem}>
                        <span>{prod.nombre}</span>
                        <span>
                          {prod.cantidad} x ${product.precio.toFixed(2)}
                        </span>
                        <span>
                          $
                          {calcularSubTotal(product.precio, prod.cantidad).toFixed(
                            2
                          )}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    )
                  })}
              </div>
              <div className={modales.Total}>
                <span>Total:</span>
                <span>${calcularTotal().toFixed(2)}</span>
              </div>
              {/* <button type='submit' className={modales.CheckoutButton}>
                Realizar Pedido
              </button> */}
              <PagoButton formData={formData} setFormData={setFormData} />
            </div>
          </form>
        </section>
      )
    }
    
    export { CheckoutPage }

Este es el error que me tira Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'precio')

Aunque no indicas en qué parte recibes este error, un posible sospechoso es lo siguiente: const product = getProductById(prod.id). Estás usando el valor de  product obtenido al llamar a esa función, sin usar una comprobación de que realmente está encontrando algo. El método find del Objeto Array en javascript devuelve el primer elemento encontrado que conicida con el parámetro de búsqueda o undefined. Si el valor de productId no se encuentra en el Array de productos, entonces te está devolviendo precisamente undefined. Verifica tu lógica y comenta el resultado.
